# Brace expansion with step increment not working bash

Tags: bash, unix, paste

I'm trying to stack some text files as new columns. The files are named energies_Strength0.0BosonsXXX.txt where XXX is 80,90,100 or 110. When I run the following command:

```
paste energies_Strength0.0Bosons{110..80..10}.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > energies_Strength0.0.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
paste: energies_Strength0.0Bosons{110..80..10}.txt: No such file or directory
paste: energies_Strength0.1Bosons{110..80..10}.txt: No such file or directory
paste: energies_Strength0.05Bosons{110..80..10}.txt: No such file or directory
paste: energies_Strength0.15Bosons{110..80..10}.txt: No such file or directory
```

This same command works just fine if files are indexed in unit steps. This is, if XXX={80,81,82,...,109,110} and I run the command:

```
 paste energies_Strength0.0Bosons{110..80}.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > energies_Strength0.0.txt
```

EDIT:

Hello there, I have tried the following lines based on your idea:

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
LANG=C 

for ((i=110; i>=80; i-=10));
do
paste energies_Strength0.0Bosons$i.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > energies_Strength0.0.txt
done
```

but it only pastes the ...Bosons80.txt file. I need to build an structure like the following:

```
paste ...80.txt ...90.txt ...100.txt ...110.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > energies_Strength0.0.txt
```

Comment: Run `echo {110..80..10}.txt` and see what you get.

Comment: I simply get `{110..80..10}.txt` which I guess it means expanding is just not wot working. Btw, `echo {110..80}.txt` does work. I'm on OSX 10.6.4

Comment: was nobody going to mention the possibility of `{11..8}0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{110..80..10}` syntax is only supported on BASH 4+ VERSIONS.

On OSX your BASH version is 3.2.xx

You can use this alternative arithmetic looping:

```
for ((i=110; i>=80; i-=10)); do echo $i.txt; done
```

Answer (score 5):

bash >=4 `{100..80..10}`

bash <4 you could `seq 80 10 100`

example:

```
kent$ seq -f '%g.txt' 80 10 110
80.txt
90.txt
100.txt
110.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`{A..B}` is well-defined Bash syntax called [brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion), when `A` and `B` are integers. `{A..B..C}` does not follow this pattern, so it's interpreted as a **literal**.